# Slicing groups after groupby and plotting in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe which in reality is a dataframe that is much larger and has been grouped based on 12 different columns. Some of the group labels coincide.

I am having trouble slicing the dataframes for plotting after grouping them with Groupby.

I would like to plot the input and output of all the groups that have car in column A and produce a legend that labels them with the values of A and B.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane',],
                   'B': ['one','one', 'two', 'two', 'three','three', 'one', 'one', 'two','two',  'three','three',],
                   'Input1': np.random.randn(12),
                   'Output1': np.random.randn(12)})
print(df_test)

grouped = df_test.groupby(['A', 'B'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouped.plot(x='Input1', y='Output1', ax=ax, legend=False)
```

So here I plot all the groups but I actually want only to plot the groups that contain car in column A

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
The below code is after using groupby.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane',],
                   'B': ['one','one', 'two', 'two', 'three','three', 'one', 'one', 'two','two',  'three','three',],
                   'Input1': np.random.randn(12),
                   'Output1': np.random.randn(12)})
print(df_test)

grouped = df_test.groupby(['A', 'B'])
grouped=grouped.first().reset_index()
grouped=grouped.loc[grouped['A']=='car']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouped.plot(x='Input1', y='Output1', ax=ax, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

If you want to filter only values which are equal to `'car'` in column A, you can try below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane',],
                   'B': ['one','one', 'two', 'two', 'three','three', 'one', 'one', 'two','two',  'three','three',],
                   'Input1': np.random.randn(12),
                   'Output1': np.random.randn(12)})
print(df_test)

grouped=df_test.loc[df_test['A']=='car']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouped.plot(x='Input1', y='Output1', ax=ax, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

Update:
Try the below code too.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane', 'plane',],
                   'B': ['one','one', 'two', 'two', 'three','three', 'one', 'one', 'two','two',  'three','three',],
                   'Input1': np.random.randn(12),
                   'Output1': np.random.randn(12)})
print(df_test)

grouped=df_test.loc[df_test['A']=='car']
grouped = grouped.groupby(['A','B'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouped.plot(x='Input1', y='Output1', ax=ax, legend=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know how exactly the OP wants the plot to look like but there are 6 rows containing 'car'. Your method generates only 3 points. What happens to the other 3 values in the plot? Add `print (grouped)` to see what I mean.

Comment: I thought that OP wants to plot after using groupby. Anyway I updated my answer.Thanks @Sheldore for pointing it out.

Comment: Every group of A and B have 2 output values. By executing grouped=grouped.first().reset_index() I lose the data series that were in the group and I am left with a data frame that only has one output value for a specific group. So unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: Thanks @ShehanIshanka. Is it not possible with using groupby?

Comment: If you use groupby to filter only values that equal to 'car' ,that is wrong.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to split a pandas DataFrameGroupBy object.   You can either filter the dataframe before the groupby, or use `filter` after groupby which returns part of the original dataframe then group again to plot.